Channel mapping in FFmpeg conversion of Dolby 7.1 mlp file to 8 channel wav file
I have a mlp file with 7.1 audio with the following channel mapping (viewed using MediaInfo): L R C LFE Ls Rs Lb Rb
I want to convert it to an 8 channel riff64 wave file, so I'm using the following command:
ffmpeg.exe -i "input.mlp" -rf64 auto -c:a pcm_f32le "output.wav"

When I do this, the channel mapping in output.wav changes to (viewed using MediaInfo): L R C LFE Lb Rb Ls Rs
I'm not sure if this is just a label that gets slapped on there, or if it actually changes the channel positions (i.e., rear surround comes out of side surround speakers and vice versa).
Is there a better command I should be using to ensure that the channel mapping is not altered?

try to extract channels to separate files: ffmpeg -i Nums_7dot1_24_48000.wav -filter_complex "channelsplit=7.1[a][b][c][d][e][f][g][h]" -map '[a]' 1.wav -map '[b]' 2.wav -map '[c]' 3.wav -map '[d]' 4.wav -map '[e]' 5.wav -map '[f]' 6.wav -map '[g]' 7.wav -map '[h]' 8.wav change 7.1 to actual layout, maybe 7.1(wide)
